# Auto smart ports macros triggers

Tags: switch, switchport

My question is simple: I have a Catalyst 3560-X series switch  and the below macro applied when i connect my laptop to the switch and it's working fine .

```
function My_laptop_func()
{
 if [[ $LINKUP == YES  ]]
  then conf t
  interface $INTERFACE
  switchport access vlan 99
  exit
  end
 fi
 if [[ $LINKUP == NO ]]
  then conf t
  interface $INTERFACE
  no switchport access vlan 99
  exit
  end
 fi
}
```

But the problem is that even though I activated `macro auto port sticky` on my interfaces, when a link-down event occurs, the `if [[ $LINKUP == NO ]]` part does not work .

Why doesn'it it work?

Comment: Please consider adding more details. "It does not work" isn't a problem description. How did you apply the macro , what logs and error messages did you get, what have you tried to fix it? Keep in mind that a switch port in access mode needs to be assigned to a vlan, so you will have to move the port to another vlan instead of using '`no switchport access vlan 99`'

Comment: Ty for answering me ! The probleme is , for example i connect my laptotp to the switch port gi0/1  it goes to vlan 99 , so far so good , but when i take  off the rg45 from gi0/1 then  i have a linkdown .Unfortunatly when i cheek for sh vlan i still find int gi0/1 in vlan 99

Comment: Does it actually matter? If the link is down, then no traffic can be on the link, so the concept of VLAN is moot. A VLAN, simply determines which traffic will use the interface, but no traffic will use an interface that is down.

Comment: maybe it does not matter . but what if it is a configuration that need to be disabled when the link is down .i hope u understand me , this is just the begging of what i ought to do .Ty for ur answers i really appreciate

Comment: Any bright ideas guys ? pliiz

Comment: I found the solution  . i Think this macro description $TRIGGER have some kind of relation with activating the linkdown event and the remove operation

Comment: this is the new script :

Comment: function My_laptop_func()
{
 if [[ $LINKUP == YES ]]
  then conf t
  interface $INTERFACE
  macro description $TRIGGER
  
  description ****Asus Laptop*******
  switchport access vlan 99
  exit
 fi
 if [[ $LINKUP == NO ]]
  then conf t
  interface $INTERFACE
  no macro description $TRIGGER
  no description  ********NO Asus laptop *********
  no switchport access vlan 99
  exit
 fi
 end
}

Comment: now it's working fine ty for ur advice and help guys !!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, 'no shut' will bring the link up, so I don't see a way to avoid the loop there. Can you trigger the macro on some other event, instead of linkup?

What would be the operational goal of the macro? Just to see if there's an alternate way to achieve that.
Do you really need the shut - no shut sequence? You could just change the vlan, the first DHCP packet might be lost, by the time the client retries, he's in the new vlan.

Plan B: MAC authentication bypass (MAB). It was basically built for this, it's just interesting to configure... :)

Comment: it's a mac authentification the macro only works when my laptop is connected :/ . i only want when i have a linkdown event  the interface changes it vlan to the original